# What informal and formal letter/e-mail closings are used the most?

Tags: grammar, british-english, letter-writing

I often struggle with doubts about the correctness of the closings which I use. I'm not a native speaker and I'm worried that I'll make a mistake in the last part of the letter/e-mail.

Some examples:

Formal:

```
I look forward to hearing from you soon.
If you need any more information, please let me know
```

Informal:

```
I hope to hear from you soon.
If you need any more info, just drop me a line.
```

Could you let me know which closings are used the most?

Comment: The question that @Mari-LouA links to seems concerned with what are usually called [valedictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction). I'd say that this question seems perhaps more concerned with the paragraph that might precede a valediction. A line like "I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon." could reasonably precede "Kind regards, Joe Bloggs".

Comment: @tobyink  Both solutions offered by the OP are *informal*, the second has an even friendlier tone. If the OP had to send an email to a client, an acquaintance, his/her boss etc., many would consider these closings/endings/valedictions inappropriate. The link I provided should help the OP, if he reads the post and finds it doesn't, then he can/should say so in his question. I'm not dismissing his request, I'm saying he might find the "duplicate" question useful.

Comment: @tobyink Yes, you're right, I'm concerned about the paragraph which precedes the valediction.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know that the formal letter should end with a statement such as "Kind regards", "Best regards", "Regards" or something similar. The tone which you're writing about is obvious for you, however the same sentence translated to my language doesn't necessarily have the same tone, that's why I'd like to understand the nuances of these closings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are fine, you are correct about the relative formality of the closings.

However, to preserve the formality in the first I would change it to "I look forward to...".